# Tailwind CSS - class does not exist error

Tags: tailwind-css

I am new to Tailwind CSS. I got this error while building a React project:

> The `hover:` class does not exist. If `hover:` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

I found a similar problem on StackOverflow but it isn't helping me. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```css
//Index.css 
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer components {
    .btn-purple {
        @apply px-4 py-1 text-sm text-purple-600 font-semibold border border-purple-200 rounded-full hover: text-white hover:bg-purple-600 hover:border-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-purple-600 focus:ring-offset-2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `@layer` here, you can also just put your custom classes between `@tailwind components;` and `@tailwind utilities;`.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't use `//` for comments in CSS files, only `/* */`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not identifying the hover property because of space after `hover:` in `text-white`.
Remove the space after the hover

```
hover:text-white
```

Comment: Still not working. I saw the space issue, I don't know why when I click the format document option, vs code adds an extra space ```hover:  text-white``` . I removed ```hover: text-white``` from my code, still showing the same error.

Comment: See if there's a space after hover at other occurences

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to simply save without formatting in order to avoid this behavior. You can also disable some auto-formatting settings in VSC.

I've also answered this in your [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8754):

Save using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This is the VSC shortcut to Save without formatting ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GcF1.png))

Comment: A similar issue for me was caused by this. Formatting introduced some spaces after some parameters and that didnt work.

Comment: Not sure if you followed the steps laid out in my original post as you mentioned "formatting" - my point was exactly the opposite, you have to **save without formatting**... which would save your file without changing any part of your code including spaces.

Answer (score -3):

You'll have to make a new selector and then put all the hover elements in there.

```
.btn-purple {
    @apply classA classB;
}

.btn-purple:hover {
    @apply hoverClassC hoverClassD;
}
```

Make sure you don't put hover: in front of the hover classes though

Comment: The OP is dealing with the Tailwind CSS framework, not plain CSS.